# Proof that $a + 1 = 1$ (Boolean algebra)

Tags: boolean-algebra

The proof works like this:

$$a + 1 = (a + 1) * 1 = (a + 1) * (a + \lnot a) = a + (1 * \lnot a) = a + \lnot a = 1$$

It only uses the axioms of Boolean algebra. I understand every step besides the third one. He uses the distributive law here but I simply don't see how.

Comment: $$(\color{blue}{ a +} 1) *(\color{blue}{ a +} \lnot a) = \color{blue}{ a +}(1*\lnot a)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two distributive laws in Boolean algebra (which are De Morgan duals of each other). The one in use here is
$$(x+y)(x+z)=x+yz $$
with $x=a$, $y=1$, $z=\neg a$.

Answer (score 0):

by using this property $a+a'=1 $

$a+1=a+(a+a')=a+a'=1$

Comment: Why is $a + (a+ a') = a + a'$?

Comment: in boolean $(a+a=a)$ not $2a$